# how to correctly calculate amountTokenMin and amountETHMin for UniSwap removeliquidityeth?

Tags: uniswap

https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router01/#removeliquidityeth

How do i safely/correctly calculate the amountETHMin and amountTokenMin when calling this function from a contract? I could just use 0's but my tx will probably get frontrun/sandwiched.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Calculated through slippage setting.
It should not be set to 0, but should be set to a value calculated with some acceptable range you think.
The attacker has no motivation to do frontrun/sandwiched. In order for an attacker to perform such an attack, a large amount of tokens must be swapped, but the attack is not useful due to the slippage setting.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Could you help me figure out exactly what math needs to be performed to calculate these inputs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**amountTokenMin = liquidity*reserveToken/totalSupply**

**amountETHMin = liquidity*reserveETH/totalSupply**

However, only use this function when WETH is involved in pool, [as per docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/guides/smart-contract-integration/providing-liquidity)

*Link is dead; so re-posted from [UniswapV2Router02.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L120); also see screen shot below:*
[image]